# Why is my redux selector not behaving correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand reselect and so far failing. I get that they are there for performance etc. should it stop mapStateToProps from being called if no state changes happen for that component?

I have this component

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ data: { complete } }) => ({
    isComplete: complete,
})
```

this gets called on every state change, I only want it to get called when the state changes from false to true

so I tried this

```
const checkIfIsComplete = () => createSelector((state, props) => props.data.complete)

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    const getIsComplete = checkIfIsComplete()
    return (state, ownProps) => {
        return {
            complete: getIsComplete(state, ownProps),
        }
    }
}
```

however, this is breaking with this error: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

how can I fix this component so it only calls mapStateToProps when it needs too and always return the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

No, you're misunderstanding how `mapState` works.  `mapState` will *always* be called any time the root state has changed.

The point of memoizing selectors here is to ensure that your `mapState` returns the same values if the state this component cares about hasn't changed, because `connect` uses shallow comparisons of the return value to decide if your component should re-render.

Please read through [the React-Redux usage guide on `mapState`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) for guidance on how to use `mapState` correctly.  My post on [Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/) discusses why and how to use Reselect.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the article only gives example if I want to do some logic in mapStateToProps, which shouldn't really be there anyway. how does reselect apply to my simple example?

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking here.  Per your original question of "how can I fix this component so it only calls mapStateToProps when it needs too and always return the correct value?", that's a wrong understanding of `mapState`. You _can't_ stop it from being called, that's the point. It _will_ be called. It's your job to return the data this component needs, and let `connect` detect when that data has changed. Selectors optimize that by skipping transformations and returning identical references if appropriate.

Comment: sorry let me be clearer.  I understand the bit about mapStateToProps gets called everytime but the second article you linked, seems to talk about doing expensive logic in mapStateToProps. seems like an anti pattern to me, that logic shouldn't live in there anyway. 

secondly, I would like an example for mine that I can follow so I can understand what is going on so I'd like to put console.logs somewhere to see what effect the selector is having on the code. I guess the selector would render the first time it gets the value, then cache it every time until it gets a new value.

Comment: my example is just getting some data from state and returning either true or false. no fancy mapping in there. as far as I can tell mapStateToProps should never do mapping logic. this should be done in the component and then update the state like that

Comment: An example of an "expensive transformation" would be something as simple as mapping over a list of item IDs to return a list of the actual items from normalized state. That creates new array references every time it's called. (Or it _could_ be something that's truly expensive to calculate.) The point is that you only want that logic running when the input values have actually changed, but `mapState` still needs to return the current correct value for use in the component, so memoized selectors can help with that.

Comment: I see that but does that mean in my case, a selector wouldn't really gain much value? I haven't got any expensive stuff happening in my app in `mapState` so maybe I'm struggling to see the case. all filtering/mapping/reducing etc happens in the component itself, not in the redux container or mapState function. `mapState` for me, just retrieves the data from the store. is it not an anti pattern to put mapping logic in the `mapState` function anyway?

Comment: Please take the time to read through the article and the docs page I linked, as they explain why memoization is often very important to good application performance - it can help avoid unnecessary re-renders even if the transformations aren't expensive in terms of CPU cycles.  And no, it's _not_ an "anti-pattern to put mapping logic in `mapState`", and I'm not sure where you're getting that idea in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your selectors like this:

```
const selectData = state => state.data;

const selectIsComplete = createSelector(
  selectData,
  (data) => data.complete
)

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
  selectIsComplete,
  //only create a new object with complete property
  //  if complete changes
  complete=>({complete})
)
```

The component will still re render if ownProps change but provided it doesn't have ownProps then this will only re render when complete changes.

Comment: ok great! I'll give this a go. how can I be measure or see that performance has improved? can I put logs somewhere and count the number of re-renders?

Comment: @RedBaron You could put console logs in the render part of the component and use react dev tools called `*Profiler`